# After git rebase, cannot merge PR because of conflict

Tags: git

I ran a `git rebase` to reorder and remove commits from the history. After which, I changed the `HEAD` code a little bit. Now I created a PR to merge these changes into develop and I am getting a PR conflict. If I do a git merge that might pull in unwanted commits... Or maybe it won't, I am not sure. How do I resolve this PR conflict the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, pull all relevant branches locally, and then merge *from the target branch* (i.e. `master`) to *your branch* (i.e. `feature`).

Examine the end result (read the resulting code, run the tests, run the app), if you're happy with that, *push the merge commit to your branch*, and then PR. You will not have conflicts then.

If you are unhappy with the results, fix them on your branch locally (after the merge), commit, then push and PR. Again, you shouldn't have conflicts then.